# ASP.Net MVC, RenderPartial to string with ViewModel data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I am attempting to render a partial view to a string from within a controller. I am using the following which is working well:

```
    StringBuilder ViewBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter ViewWriter = new StringWriter(ViewBuilder))
    {
        ViewEngineResult ViewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(PageController.ControllerContext, controlName);
        ViewContext ViewContext = new ViewContext(PageController.ControllerContext, ViewResult.View, PageController.ViewData, PageController.TempData, ViewWriter);
        ViewResult.View.Render(ViewContext, ViewWriter);
    }
    return ViewBuilder.ToString();
```

Reference: http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

However I would like to be able to load typed model data into this view as well. I am looking for ideas on how this might be done.

Thanks

---

**Edit**:

It turns out I was looking in the wrong spot. I was able to set it using the ViewDataDictionary, see below:

```
ViewDataDictionary ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
ViewData.Model = GetModelState();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Model is a property of View or ViewContext.

Comment: I've looked into it some more, it's a property off of the view data.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this.
http://blog.learningdds.com/?p=87

It is an extension method for the controller that renders the HTML in a View / PartialView to a String.

The code for it is here: http://learningdds.com/public/ControllerExtension.cs

It is based on the blog you refered to above.